# ReactJS: how to immediately update component after changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My page needs to fetch data from server which may take several seconds. Thus I want to display "Loading..." while fetching. So I have a boolean state variable `loading` to indicate whether it is fetching data. If `loading` is `true`, `render()` function display "Loading now", otherwise it displays "Not loading". However, it turns out that react cannot re-render component after setting `loading` to true.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codecancer/p4Lsnoqk/).

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            loading: false,
        };
    },

    handleClick: function() {
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        }, function() {
            // dummy loop to simulate fetching data
            for (var i=0;i<=100000;i++) {
                console.log("dummy");
            }

            this.setState({
                loading: false,
            });
        }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        load
                    </button>
                    <p>Loading now</p>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    load
                </button>
                <p>Not Loading</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: There's no `fetching` variable in the code. Did you mean `loading` ?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because JS is single-threaded. When you run your loop *whole page* freeze. So it does not React issue.

Fetching data is asynchronous action and it does not freeze page.
You can emulate it with `setTimeout`. And it this case all work correctly.

Example:

```
handleClick: function(){
  this.setState({
    loading: true
  }, function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
     });
    }.bind(this), 3000)
  }.bind(this));
},
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzhiriki/8w8uk8kd/)

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know that. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

you might try to think like this;

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        loading: false
    };
  },

  handleClick: function(){
    fetch("http://sampleurl.com")
    .then(function(data){
      //if success
      this.setState({loading: true})
    })
  },

  render: function() {
  var result;
  if(this.state.loading == true){
    result = <p>Loading Now</p> 
  } else {
    result = <p>Not Loading</p>
  }
    return (
       <div>
         <button onClick={this.handleClick}>load</button>
         {/*render variable result here*/}
         {result}
       </div>);
  }
});
```

Comment: For your information the second argument of setState is a callback called after the update is finished. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate